# Check if Excel file is empty in C#

Tags: c#

Can anyone suggest, how to check if xls file empty or not?
I have tried `FileInfo("fname").Length == 0`  But it's not working.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to avoid Excel automation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "empty" Excel file will still have an Excel file header, which is why your test for a size of 0 is failing.

You can use [Excel Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms262200%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to see what the [UsedRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.usedrange%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/b9cdfbd7-5ae9-41f7-b7e8-ebc00e835d45#546316e8-8745-42e8-9c0d-063d1373dfbe

Comment: Beware of UsedRange. See there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434444/worksheet-usedrange-rows-count-returns-wrong-result

Answer (score 2):

for `.xls` you can try this - it works for me.

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/FileUpload/") + path.Value);
                Workbook book = Workbook.Load(Server.MapPath(("~/FileUpload/") + FileUpload1.FileName));
                Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];
                sheetCount.Value = sheet.Cells.LastRowIndex.ToString();

                foreach (Worksheet ws in book.Worksheets)
                {
                    if (ws.Cells.Rows.Count != 0)
                    {
                        ddlSheets.Items.Add(ws.Name.ToString());
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not simple solution similar to one you have stated.

You will have to actually programatically read the file by some Excel parser and check if there are some data.

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel Interop I have created this function. It works as Ribbon add-in, however you can replace `Globals.ThisAddIn` with `Excel.Application`.

```
private bool IsEmptyFolder(Excel.Workbook wb)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach(Excel.Worksheet sheet in wb.Worksheets)
                {
                    if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheet.Cells) != 0) return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

If it finds any worksheet with a value in a cell, it returns false. Otherwise it returns true (the workbook is empty).