# Searching a word + autofilter

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter, keyword-search

I want to autofilter a matrix according to a word search in a specific column (the column has long texts -string-).

The macro copies the autofiltered cells and pastes them in a new book. I am finding a problem to autofilter the arrange for all words-like the key word.

E.g. I use the word "circuit" and get only one row with results but there are two additional rows with the word "circuits". If I used the word "circuits", I don't get any result.

How can I autofilter the arrange by finding a word without an exact match?

This is the relevant part of my code:

```vb
Sub Enviardatosfiltrados()
    Dim wbLibroActual As Workbook
    Dim wsHojaActual As Worksheet
    Dim RangoDatos As Range
    Dim uFila As Long
    Dim wbLibroNuevo As Workbook
    
    Set wbLibroActual = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)
    Set wsHojaActual = wbLibroActual.ActiveSheet
    
    Set RangoDatos = wsHojaActual.UsedRange
    
    RangoDatos.AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="=*" & "circuit" & "*"
    
    uFila = wsHojaActual.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: have you tried using `Criteria1:="*circuit*"`?

Comment: [Never rely on UsedRange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434444/why-i-use-worksheet-usedrange-rows-count-got-wrong-result/50434743#50434743)

Comment: @ Hi... I just did it and it didn't work. I got the same unuseful results.

Comment: @JohnyL Thanks.. I actually changed it. However, I cannot solve my problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

Just add this Operator to your definition:

```
RangoDatos.AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="=*" & "circuit" & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Hint: Record macro on your Developer tab, and change your autofilter to get the right code.