# Finding Last row using usedrange

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a large macro code for automating my daily office report.
I am using following code for getting Last row.

```
Lrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
```

in what cases this code will end up giving wrong results.

Like using "xlup from last cell of column" is useless when data is not in tabular form.
Eg. column 1 have 10 cells & column 2 have 25 cells.

Comment: I've found the range.Find with xlByRows and xlPrevious to be the most reliable method for ragged data.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ is there a reason you removed excel-vba tag?

Comment: @CallumDA Tag description says *THIS TAG IS PENDING REMOVAL. Instead, please use tags [excel] and [vba]. (More info: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370095)*

Comment: Gaurav if you feel this is not a duplicate or the linked post doesn't provide a solution to your query then let me know and I will re-open it :)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, thanks I didn't realise that

Comment: @SiddharthRout, while the question isn't a duplicate -- the answer definitely covers this question too (nice answer btw). If only that other question was called something more like *"How to find the last row on a sheet"*

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am trying this code, which is not frequently used. I want you guys to let me know, in which situations my code can go wrong?

Comment: Did you go through the link that I sahred?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yup, I saw your answer & also agree that it gives correct answer. But I am trying alternate options.

Comment: No I meant, Did you read about the "usedrange" part. I was referring to `I want you guys to let me know, in which situations my code can go wrong? – Gaurav Jain 7 mins ago`

Comment: It took some time. But I read that complete thread. Thank you. Got what I needed. Have a nice day everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the last `Row` in a sheet using find. e.g.

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Comment: I usually include something like an `After:=ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.RowsCount, ActiveSheet.ColumnsCount)`  argument.

Comment: @user11246173 I don't think you need it - but doesn't hurt either

Comment: Can you try this code with a excel data in which column 1 have 10 cells & column 2 have 25 cells. It end up giving Row("10") as last row, while my last row is Row("25")

Comment: @GauravJain I've set up a workbook with 10 rows in column 1, and 25 rows in column 2 and it comes back with 25. Can you update your question with the code that you're trying and is failing?

Comment: Done its working. But can you tell me issues in my code.

Comment: Nothings wrong with your code. Just `UsedRange` can give unexpected results so is usually best to avoid when trying to get the last row of a sheet. Have a look at this answer - it explains it a bit more. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434593/3042759)