# Copy and paste values by range, not by cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the below piece of code to paste the values I want as values, but to do it by block range, not cell by cell.

I've tried the below code and a few other examples, but this one gets as close to what I want.

```
Sub main()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
For i = 6 To 30
    If IsEmpty(Sheets("Main").Cells(i, 6).Value) = False Then

    Sheets("SSCC_Bin").UsedRange 'refreshes sheet2
    LastRow = Sheets("SSCC_Bin").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("SSCC_Bin").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row 'find the number of used rows

    Sheets("Main").Cells(i, 5).Offset(0, -2).Copy
    Sheets("SSCC_Bin").Range("A1").Offset(LastRow, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'copies and pastes the data

Else
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I have formula's in column C of sheet 'Main' which are order numbers. I want them moved in one motion to SSCC_Bin. The code above does it cell by cell which plays with my formula's.

Comment: `Sheets("Main").Cells(i, 5).Offset(0, -2).Copy` You are copying online 1 single cell. You need to modify this part to copy the range you want to.

Comment: Try avoiding `UsedRange`. Please check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434743/6908282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using something like the following. This will 'copy' the values in your `Main` sheet in blocks based on where the empty cells are

```
Sub main()
    Dim LastRow As Long, DestRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    With Sheets("SSCC_Bin")
        DestRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With Sheets("Main")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 6 To LastRow
            ' Skips over empty cells
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 6)) Then
                ' Gets CurrentRegion - basically all surrounding cells that are populated
                With Intersect(.Cells(i, 6).CurrentRegion, .Columns(6))
                    ' Same as PasteSpecial xlPasteValues but faster           
                    Sheets("SSCC_Bin").Cells(DestRow, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value2 = .Value2
                    ' Updates where the next data set is to be added too
                    DestRow = DestRow + .Rows.Count
                    ' Increase i for the rows that we have already handled
                    i = i + .Rows.Count
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your time. I only want the values in column C, the CurrentRegion i tried, but also brings every other column with it?

Comment: @Ceebee86 Have updated - can you try again with my edit?

Comment: Thats great, modified it a little to go for last row after. :)

Comment: Just add one to your `LastRow` variable or is that not what you mean? i.e. `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: to get the scenario I wanted, I added the +1 after DestRow 
                                     -----------------Sheets("SSCC_Bin").Cells(DestRow + 1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value2 = .Value2

Answer (score 0):

The following code should probably work for you. I have not tested this yet.

Instead of looping through each cell and checking if its empty, you can use `SpecialCells` function to find constants.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim LastRow As Long    

    Sheets("SSCC_Bin").UsedRange 'refreshes sheet2
    LastRow = Sheets("SSCC_Bin").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("SSCC_Bin").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row 'find the number of used rows

    Sheets("Main").Range("F6:F30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Copy
    Sheets("SSCC_Bin").Range("A1").Offset(LastRow, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

**Note**: This code does not work if your range has formula's

Comment: You might benefit from reading this [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/3042759)

Comment: Thank you @Tom. I've updated the code to not include Select

Comment: Hi Gangula, I get run time error 1004 when trying to run it? :(

Comment: I was not able to figure out where exactly you want it to be pasted. The `UsedRange` function is not preferable. Can you let me know where exactly you want it pasted? Please add it within the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have another answer, here is a basic solution with comments.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
    'Hide the rows in column 6 if the cell is empty
    .Columns(6).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True

    'Copy only the visible cells in the range
    .Range("C6:C30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    'paste the range to the next cell after the last used cell in column A
    Sheets("SSCC_Bin").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End With

'Clear the marching ants
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```