# How can I save all sheet contents in a variable and then return it back to my sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a big sheet of data that changes after I run through some code.
I was thinking about a way to bring all that data back to life before running the code. I want to do this without creating any new sheets - just store the values in an object/variable and return it back after running my code.

I've tried doing something like

```
Dim myrng As Range

myrng = sheets(x).Usedrange  'storing the sheet contents

SheetS(x).Range("A1") = myrng 'bringing back original sheet contents to the same sheet
```

I know this might look stupid but I really have no idea if I should be doing some copy-paste application or whatsoever.

Comment: `UsedRange` will only store the Address. Like in Real life, your Home Address, but not anything about who lives there. That can change, but address won't

Comment: Yeah, that's what I kind of thought. So how can I store the contents?

Comment: Simplest way would be to create a New Sheet and delete after operation is done. But as you don't want to do that, you can create an array and save all the values of the UsedRange in It. then you can loop and Print them Back.

Comment: @JurasSulcas, What if you programmatically created a new sheet, copied the range, and then deleted it after pasting back (all programmatically?)

Comment: @JurasSulcas ..See the Answer. You can save the Contents in a Array and Print it back like that

Comment: Try avoiding `UsedRange`. Please refer this answer: stackoverflow.com/a/50434743/6908282

Answer (score 1):

**This will Work:**

```
Dim rng As String
Dim dat() As Variant

rng = Sheets(x).UsedRange.Address
dat = Sheets(x).UsedRange.Value  'storing the sheet contents

'Do changes on Sheet

Sheets(x).Range(rng) = dat()
```

**Explanation:**

- Saved the ***Address*** of `UsedRange` in a `String`
- Saved the ***Contents*** of `UsedRange` in a `Array`
- Pasted the `Array` Back in the ***Saved Address*** in 1st Step

Comment: Try avoiding `UsedRange`. Please refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434743/6908282

Comment: @Gangula `UsedRange` is applicable in this situation. What you are referring to is getting an _absolute_ row/column from the `UsedRange` via `UsedRange.Rows.Count` or `UsedRange.Columns.Count`. Doesn't matter if Rows 1 through 500.000 are empty in this case, since `UsedRange.Address` will still give us the address of row 500.001.

Comment: Thank you @Nacorid, I didn't realize that.