# "No column information was returned" error when selecting from empty Excel sheet

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I have an Excel workbook that contains a series of sheets for import into a database. For most of the sheets I'm using a query to get at the data along the lines of:

```
SELECT [F1], [F2] FROM [Sheet Name$A2:B10000]
```

In my development I had a workbook with some test data for each sheet. Now someone else is using the package to import a copy of the workbook, but one of the sheets is blank because they don't want any data loaded for that particular table. Unfortunately, when the package tries to run that portion of the import it errors out with a `VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA` error.

This can't be a unique problem, but I haven't been able to find any solutions online. Any suggestions on how to get around it?

Comment: Try setting `ValidateExternalMetadata` to False on the Excel Source connection. Setting `DelayValidation` to True may also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a similar case, I would use a Script Task to check if the Excel sheet contains data, if so, the Data Flow Task is executed (using precedence constraints).

Also, make sure to set the Data Flow Task `Delay Validation` property to `True`.

#### Useful links:

- [Check if Excel file is empty in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003045/check-if-excel-file-is-empty-in-c-sharp)
- [How to check if Excel-workbook is empty?](https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3374236/How-to-check-if-Excel-workbook-is-empty.aspx)
- [Working with Precedence Constraints in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/working-with-precedence-constraints-in-sql-server-integration-services/)